# create a swc file for existing flex application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, swc

I had flex project with few action script files.

I want to make the project as swc file. So can i know how to create it as swc file.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you are using Flash Builder, create a Flex library project and add the code there as you would in a normal project. There will be an extra pane in the Build settings allowing you to choose which classes to include (it defaults to everything). When you compile you will get a .swc file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Flex's component compiler.  Check out [compc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fd2.html).